# How to draw circles in each of the rectangles end point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am new to javascript and I wanted to draw something like this:

[image: what I want]

but I ended up being able to draw only a rectangle like this:

```
Rectangle(data){
this.canvas.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('data-id', (d) => d.matchId)
            .attr('data-algorithm', (d) => d.algorithm)
            .attr('class', 'match match__rectangle')
            .attr('x', (d) => d.x)
            .attr('y', (d) => d.y)
            .attr('width', (d) => d.width)
            .attr('height', (d) => d.height)
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('stroke', (d) => d.color);
    }
```

can someone help me draw those little circles in the endpoints of each line of the rectangle?

Do I need to reconsider drawing lines and circles and then connect them or I can do it like this with rect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to paint those circles, and the more adequate one depends on what you want to do with them.

For instance, if you don't want to bind any (meaningful) data to those circles, you can use an `each` with the rectangles' selection to get the corner of each rectangle and append the circle (to the SVG, not to the rectangle, which is impossible).

So, for each rectangle, we get the coordinates for the four circles...

```
var circlePositions = [
    [d.x, d.y],
    [d.x + d.width, d.y],
    [d.x, d.y + d.height],
    [d.x + d.width, d.y + d.height]
];
```

... and append them:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(circlePositions)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d[0])
    .attr("cy", d => d[1])
```

Here is a demo with bogus data, for 3 rectangles:

```js
var data = [{x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 20},
  {x: 200, y: 80, width: 50, height: 120},
  {x: 360, y: 50, width: 120, height: 80}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr('x', d => d.x)
  .attr('y', d => d.y)
  .attr('width', d => d.width)
  .attr('height', d => d.height)
  .style('fill', 'gray')
  .style('stroke', 'black');

rects.each(d => {
  var circlePositions = [
    [d.x, d.y],
    [d.x + d.width, d.y],
    [d.x, d.y + d.height],
    [d.x + d.width, d.y + d.height]
  ];
  svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(circlePositions)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d[0])
    .attr("cy", d => d[1])
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("fill", "limegreen")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```